# Gzip is not compressing my website properly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, gzip

Gzip is not working properly. I have added the below code in .htaccess to enable gzip. but it doesnot make any change in Compressing my website:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddType x-font/otf .otf
AddType x-font/ttf .ttf
AddType x-font/eot .eot
AddType x-font/woff .woff
AddType image/x-icon .ico
AddType image/png .png
AddType text/css .css
```

In [checkgzipcompression.com](https://checkgzipcompression.com/), it says Gzip is enabled. Any ideas in solving this issue?

Comment: I suppose that checkgzipcompression.com does *not* say "It's GZIP Enabled". Can you please clarify that? In any case, you may want to check each file type in your browser's *Network* pane. Look for `Content-Encoding: gzip` in the response and verify the size in both columns (transfer and size).

Comment: How can you know it isn't working since you say that the checker says it is enabled? What is your website  address?

Comment: i checked the size of my page through tools.pingdom.com  before and after compression. i found out that the Gzip is not compressing my webpage.My website is tripsimba.com